# Why is type checking in PHP called "hinting" instead of "checking"?

Tags: php, language-lawyer, type-hinting

If I understand correctly what type hinting in php in fact does, it checks type and throws an error if it is not as declared.

That seems to me more than just a "hint" – more like a (full) "check" (like java - my main programming background).

So, I'm wondering if I'm missing something or what the intent was in naming it that way.

Comment: Maybe it is similar to an annotation like `@NotNull` which allows static analysis to help with coding errors where null might be assigned, but does nothing to prevent a value of null being assigned at run-time through introspection.

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not check variable types and types are not declared within variable declaration. PHP always tries to convert variable to correct type when required. If you str_replace on number, number will be temporarily converted to string.

As you can see there http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

So its exactly the opposite from java.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure it helps much to say it is the "exact opposite" from java: the difference is more subtle than exact.  I have found that the concept I needed was coercion. Since java tends to want explicit casts, and coercion (in php) means casts are done as needed, without programmer intervention, it's coercion that allows the phrase "type hinting" to make more sense to me as a naming choice.

Comment: When I said its exact opposite, it was reaction to **more like a (full) "check" (like java - my main programming backgrond)**